# Master detail page in Xamarin Forms and MvvmCross

Tags: xamarin.forms, mvvmcross

I have a Index.xaml page which has the following PagePresentation:

```
[MvxMasterDetailPagePresentation(Position = MasterDetailPosition.Detail,
  WrapInNavigationPage = true, Title = "Demo")]
```

It will show the hamburger icon in the navigation bar and all works fine.

The menu that is displayed when you click the hamburger menu has:

```
[MvxMasterDetailPagePresentation(MasterDetailPosition.Master)]
```

Now when I navigate from the detail page to a Detail.xaml I would expect that the Detail.xaml would show the back arrow in the navigation bar, but here it also shows the hamburger icon. Detail.xaml doesn't have a PagePresentation attribute.

I navigate to Index.xaml using the code:

```
_navigationService.Navigate(typeof(DetailViewModel), parameter);
```

When I remove the MvxMasterDetailPagePresentation from Index.xaml the hamburger menu is gone and Detail.xaml **does** show the back arrow but I need the hamburger icon in Index.xaml.

I played around with PagePresentations but I couldn't get it to work.

How can I achieve the desired behavior?

Answer (score 0):

As it says in the [docs](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/platform/xamarin.forms/xamarin-forms-view-presenter?scroll=879#mvxmasterdetailpagepresentationattribute):

> Position | TabbedPosition | Use this to set the position of the Page. It can either be the Root to host Pages, or as a Tab to be a Page inside the TabbedPage

You don't have any Root there to host the pages, so your Index.xaml should be set to:

```
[MvxMasterDetailPagePresentation(MasterDetailPosition.Root, WrapInNavigationPage = false)]
```

Your menu:

```
[MvxMasterDetailPagePresentation(MasterDetailPosition.Master)]
```

Your detail:

```
[MvxMasterDetailPagePresentation(MasterDetailPosition.Detail, WrapInNavigationPage = true, NoHistory = true)]
```

The [Stars wars sample](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Samples/tree/master/StarWarsSample/StarWarsSample.Forms/StarWarsSample.Forms/Views) is a good place to see it working.

HIH